# `animateKeyframesWithDuration` - high GPU

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've added a relatively simple animation that runs continuously. This is used to briefly switch to another view for a couple of seconds.

While the animation is running, the GPU jumps from <5% to a constant 30-40% on an iPhone 6 (iOS 9.2.1), while the 'Energy Impact' (Activity Monitor) on the simulator goes way up. Note that the actual animation only takes a small portion of the time (code at bottom), yet the GPU stays high the entire time. Setting a non-transparent background to the views that are animated doesn't improve things.

While the animation looks smooth, this seems weird, so I'm wondering if there's something I miss or doing wrong, or if there's some known bug regarding the `animateKeyframesWithDuration` method.

Below is a simplified code sample that leads to the same high GPU consumption:

```
v1.alpha = 0;
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:10 delay:0
                             options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear
                          animations:^
 {
     [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.9/10 relativeDuration:0.1/10 animations:^{
         v2.alpha = 0;
         v1.alpha = 1;
     }];
 } completion:nil];
```

Thanks.

**Edit to add some notes:**

1. The animation doesn't go idle, even if there's no animation instructions set for a specific time fraction of the animation (e.g. `addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime` added just for 1/10 of the total animation time).
   Being so, `animateKeyframesWithDuration:` may not be the best solution for animations with an 'idle' time (as in the code example above) - a better performance can be achieved by using a timer for instance, which starts the actual animation(s) when needed.
2. All layers that are part of the animation will animate the entire time (in the example above, v1.layer and v2.layer) - again, if there's no specific instruction set for a given time fraction, it won't go idle (it'll keep redrawing and consuming GPU, unless it's no longer visible).
3. Regarding the performance, it is comparable to other CoreAnimation animations.
   The draw code for the animations seems to be handled only internally - draw methods from `UIView` or `CALayer` are not being called during the animation. This makes it that animating any views will have similar performance results (e.g. a view/layer that draws a full rectangle will not be more performant than a `UILabel` or a more complex view/layer).

**Edit 2:**

On iOS 10 (as well as Mac OS Sierra), the animations take up a lot less resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animation is performed on a background thread and is managed frame by frame on the GPU by a special process (the "animation server"). The duration is of no interest here; you are set up to repeat forever, so that animation server has to keep performing the animation forever. That, as you've discovered, is not free. Every frame is a new calculation and a new drawing. That takes work. It doesn't get easier for the animation server to do this just because it has done the "same" animation once already. (The iPhone is not some sort of magical perpetual motion machine!)

Comment: The idea is that the actual animation (`addKeyFrameWithRelativeStartTime:..`) is only 1/10 out of the total time - the GPU is as high during the entire time. I'm not expecting anything magical here, but the animation is relatively simple, so I would have expected it to have a low impact on the GPU/energy.

Comment: You're just making me repeat myself. Did you read my answer? It tells you that it doesn't matter how "simple" you, a human, may think the animation is. The computer knows nothing of that. Every 1/60 sec, the next frame has to be calculated and the render tree must be drawn, regardless of what the animation consists of. Use Instruments (e.g. Core Animation tool) to quantify.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that if the animation block is set to 10 seconds, and the actual animation/keyframe is set from second 9 to 10, the computer will do its magical calculations starting second 0, and will redraw the same thing for the first 9 seconds, and between second 9 and 10 it would do some calculations that are so complex that a simple human mind can't comprehend. Noted.

Comment: What answer would make you happy? As I've said, Instruments will quantify all of this call by call, instant by instant. Explore what's going on and answer your own question. Though, aside from "I'm surprised", it's getting hard to see what your question _is_ at this point.